# strfind using a split array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

For my project I am trying to extract the data from a `Listbox`.
The data in the listbox is like "1 x bolt", I am trying to get the "bolt" part from this sentence. Then check in which row this word is from my Excel sheet (named "Bom"). If found then find the same row but instead of column F go to column G and insert that text in my different `Listbox2`.

So far it tells me that strsearch doesn't work with an array.

**My Code**

```
With ONDS1

    Dim PartID              As String
    Dim rSearch             As Range  'range to search
    Dim c                   As Range
    Dim i                   As Long

    With Sheets("Bom")
        Set rSearch = .Range("f1", .Range("F1000").End(xlUp))
    End With

    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox_stuklijst.ListCount - 1
        strfind = Split(Me.ListBox_stuklijst(i), , 3)
        strfind(2) = rSearch

        Set c = rSearch.Find(strfind, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "working"
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: where are you populating the `ListBox` values from ? frome a "Bom" sheet `Range` ? how ?

Comment: It combines the "aantal" which is quantity of the part with it's ID.

      lijstItem = TextBox_AantalStuks & " X " & ComboBox_ID.Value
      ListBox_stuklijst.AddItem (lijstItem)

Comment: `What` in your `.Find` cannot be an array.  So you'll need to iterate through the elements of `strfind`.  It may be faster to read `rSearch` into a VBA array, and then search through the array elements using either your `Split` method, or using Regular Expressions.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I really am a beginner, just started using VBA last week, could you explain your statement with some code.

Comment: @stckvrflw `What:` is one of the named arguments of the `.Find` method and should show up with `Intellisense`.  Your `strfind` variable is an array (look at Help for the `Split` method).  You need to loop through only one element of the array at a time, in order for the `.Find` to work.  You'll find lots of information as to how to do that with an internet search such as `vba: looping through array`